# MySQL multiple group by using

Tags: mysql, group-by

Now i using this is query :

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ReceiverID='$uid' or SenderID='$uid' GROUP BY Recei
verID,SenderID ORDER BY Datex DESC
```

But they results

```
ID  ReceiverID  SenderID
 1      2            1
 2      1            2
```

but i want to only showing one result for WHERE syntax.
for example:

```
ID  ReceiverID  SenderID
 1      2            1
```

or

```
ID  ReceiverID  SenderID
 2      1            2
```

Comment: But _which_ one do you want to show? The first? The last? SQL needs you to be as specific as possible whenever possible. What value do you eventually need? The GROUP BY isn't really acting reliably here, absent any aggregate function, and with multiple ungrouped columns in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE ReceiverID='$uid' or SenderID='$uid'
GROUP BY least(ReceiverID, SenderID), greatest(ReceiverID, SenderID)
ORDER BY Datex DESC;
```

However, you should list the columns explicitly in the `select`.  You are using a MySQL extension where you have columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  This is a bad idea unless you understand what you are really doing.

Answer (score 0):

HI Try This query,

```
SELECT * FROM messages(SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY Datex DESC) WHERE  ReceiverID='$uid' or SenderID='$uid' GROUP BY ReceiverID,SenderID
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is just one and it can be either one then why not just do a random ordering with a limit?

```
SELECT id, recieverid, senderid 
FROM
(   SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE ReceiverID='$uid' OR SenderID='$uid' 
    GROUP BY ReceiverID,SenderID 
    ORDER BY Datex DESC
) t
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```